# Создание визуального представления структуры из SQL-базы

Tags: mysql, model

Имеется база в MySQL,на сервере.

Как можно получить графически представленную структуру данной базы? Примерно такую как можно в строить в том же SQL Power Architect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), там есть такой функционал.

Answer (score 0):

Веб-клиент phpMyadmin тоже позволяет.

Comment: не могу найти,вроде как-то натыкался-но теперь не могу найти(

Comment: Кажется, нужно плагин установить.

Comment: Здесь посмотрите: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=2055